# CMS - Save pictures in database, What is the proper structure?

Tags: image, database-design, data-structures, content-management-system, filesystems

I currently build a CMS system that need to save a lot of pictures per article. I have a lot of questions :-)

I need to show the pictures in a few sizes, with or without watermark. In addition I need to have the original picture too, for archive and admin purpose. What that I think to do right now is to save the pictures in the database, in two versions: 1. the original picture, 2. web-optimized version.

1. It is really convenient way to save all the images in a table. But does it really good idea? Let say that the database will contain a hundred of thousand pictures, the original pictures size is probably around 3MB. so the db can be easily 100TB size.... Is this really good strategy?
2. On the other hand, I save a smaller version to each picture. This version need to be shown in a few sizes, with and without watermark. Currently I think to do think to this in on each request. the request will have parameters width, and according to this I can decide the size and the watermark.  (I'll cache this work of course). Again, Is this a good strategy? do it really gonna work, or this is very expensive extra work?
3. Is it really better to save this on the db? I mean each request to article, will need around 50 another requests to its images, and each request required open/close connection to the database.

Technologies that I going to use: .net, sql-server 2008, NHibernate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach would be storing those images in filesystem and ids on database. Because of performance and maintenance reasons. Backing up and restoring would be much easier on filesystem and pushing the DBMS for such a work is not the best idea, you will need to transfer them from db to application and then push to the client. I just believe that's not it's job. Put a lighttpd daemon or something for image hosting and leave it do its job.

But if you like the idea, since you are going with sql server 2008, you can use FILESTREAM to store your images in your tables. Eventually, it will create files in a storage location that you choose and store the binary data in filesystem while providing transactional features and data integrity, it is a big bonus. Take a look at that option. As I remember, that performs good and the actual database will be much compact.

About the dynamic resizing, I say avoid that. Storage is cheaper than CPU time, just create variety of thumbnails and watermarked versions upon upload time and store them once in somewhere then use when required. Do not perform same operations again and again. You may do that at first request to the resized version, this way it will be easier to add new versions or purging the cache periodically to remove unused files. You will also be able to backup just the original versions.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the images in the database has a couple of advantages. ACID tanscations and backup consistency come to mind. If you absolutely need that then put the images in the database. As you pointed out, this comes with a price: you'll need a huge database infrastructure like machines, licenses, operation team. Each image retrieval is a huge DB I/O effort.

A lot of things will be much easier with only storing metadata in the DB and putting the image blobs on a filesystem.

Two approaches to come to a decison:

- What is the killer feature you absolutely (absolutely like in "if I don't have that, the whole thing will not work at all") need from the image-in-database approach? If there is one, go for it
- Do a back-of-the-napkin business case, calculating the total cost of the image-in-database approach (project efforts, infrastructure, machine, license, operation) and compare that with an image-in-filesystem approach. That should give some hints on how to proceed.